# bash script - string comparison yields unexpected result

Tags: bash, dart, stdout, stderr

I already searched several answers, but those cannot be applied to my problem.

The problem code is below.

I think the result of `dart -version` is not a simple string.

```
DART_VER=$(dart --version)
#expect output as ==>> Dart VM version: ...
echo "${DART_VER}"

if [[ "$DART_VER" == Dart* ]]
then
 echo Dart!   # doesn't enter here
fi
```

Comment: What is output of `echo "${DART_VER}"`?

Comment: In bash, it's `-eq` instead of `==` right?

Comment: @HussainTamboli: No; `-eq` is numeric comparison, `==` is pattern-matching. The OP is correctly using the latter.

Comment: @sunglim: Can you respond to janos's question: What is output of `echo "<${DART_VER}>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `dart --version` is writing out to standard error rather than standard output. (See https://code.google.com/p/dart/codesearch#dart/trunk/dart/runtime/bin/main.cc&sq=package:dart&q=ProcessVersionOption&l=588.) So when you see your script print `Dart VM version: ...`, that's actually coming from the `DART_VER=$(dart --version)` (which prints `Dart VM version: ...` to standard error, and sets `DART_VER` to the empty string) rather than the `echo "${DART_VER}"` (which just prints the empty string, plus a newline).

You can fix that by changing this:

```
DART_VER=$(dart --version)
```

to this:

```
DART_VER=$(dart --version 2>&1)
```

to merge standard error into standard output for capture.

Comment: @janos: I addressed that in my first paragraph. The OP *thought* that `echo "${DART_VER}"` was printing `Dart VM version: ...`, but in fact that output was coming from the `DART_VER=$(dart --version)`.